# Can I prevent a second visa refusal if i have a sponsor (havin good finances)but my finances haven't changed?

Tags: visas, uk, schengen, proof-provenance-of-funds

My wife and I have been refused a visa owing to funds parking. The large deposits were made to my account by my mother and father and, in previous months, similar transfers have been made. Until the refusal, I was not aware of the term and that it is such a valid refusal reason.Now i wish to reapply with my father is my sponsor for the vacation.He has a good regular income.Im residing with him and also hold a joint account with him in a reputable bank . HE is willing to sponsor my entire trip and has already transferred the required funds in my account and has no issues in providing for any additional costs or financial assistance for the same.so if he is my sponsor is my income still of dat much importance.?he is also my employer and im workin in his company he has transferred funds to me on a regular basis towards salary&comission.(but the transfer amount varyin not uniform).Im his benefeciary&only son. And his next in command to take over his business .
I work with my father and uncles in a joint family business. I get money from him in lump sums, sometimes even more if I require it.
My work compensation for the company and for my general other expenses has been received quarterly or monthly, as and when I require it.Since i live with my father as a joint family, all the day to day sundry expenses are taken care of by my dad.

How should I explain this to the visa officer? I do not want my application to look vague .

Comment: "My work compensation for the company has been received quarterly or monthly, as and when I require it". That doesn't sound like work compensation, it sounds like your family giving you money when they feel like it. The visa officers will not see it as a steady source of income, and may question if it's a real job.

Comment: You may wish to read the accepted answer in [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) to get a better idea of what UK officials are looking for in your bank statements.

Comment: If my father will sponsor my trip ... with a due letter from him, his bank account details ,and i receive a cheque from him for the same etc .. will i still be denied ? I am working in his company . It is a joint family business since three generations .

Comment: @micheal seifert thanx for the comment. I have read that article byt sadly these are the state of my current account and i was reali hopin to do d holiday before a baby. I have a good lifestyle and my dad has a steady income and i am working with him .. i didnot consider these nitty gritties now what will be my best bet ? Is der any slim chance ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

Comment: .Should i reapply for uk visa or try for schengen visa first .what are my chances of getting schengen after uk refusal ? Are the assesment rules more or less similar . Also if i reapply  fora uk visa and get refused a second time,will i have any chances of getting a schengen visa ? I have previously travelled to france spain and switzerland

Comment: @Payalranka: five people have said your question is unclear. To get further answers, it is best for you to [edit your question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/96426/edit) and make it much clearer. You might make this question *only* about preventing a second UK refusal and [ask a new question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about how UK refusals affect Schengen applications (but check existing questions & answers first)

Comment: Sorry for that .im new to this and sort of panicking due to the refusal .

Answer (score 1):

> **Can I prevent a second visa refusal if my finances haven't changed?**

No, if the refusal was on the basis of your finances and these have not changed, the result of a new application is almost certainly going to be the same.

> **what will be my best bet**

Since the problem is that your employment income does not look like typical employment income, I think your best bet is to arrange with your employer for

- Regular monthly salary payments into your bank account. The amounts should be commensurate with the expected full-time salary of other people doing a similar job in your locale.
- Documentation such as wage slips from your employer.
- It might help to have documentation showing the appropriate income-tax or other tax deductions that would be expected from a legitimate business employment.
- Evidence that you are able to regularly save a proportion of your salary.

After a reasonable period (many months, maybe a year) your picture would almost certainly look more convincing.

---

As Micheal Seifert commented. There is very good and relevant advice in

- [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

Comment: Yes.thnx , but  the point is my father is my  sponsor for the vacation.He has a good regular income.Im residing with him and also hold a joint account with him in a reputable bank . he is willing to sponsor my entire trip and has already transferred the required funds in my account and has no issues in providing for any additional costs or financial assistance for the same.so if he is my sponsor is my income still of dat much importance.?he is also my employer and im workin in his company he has transferred funds to me on a regular basis towards salary&comission.im his benefeciary&only son.